# Strange artifact when using Canvas.drawText

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint

I have been working with a canvas, and am currently experiencing a strange issue while working with drawing text.

Below are both the code, and a partial screen capture of the issue I am seeing.

```
private Paint paint = null;

public MyObject(Context context){

    paint = new Paint(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas c){

    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint.setTextSize(30);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    c.drawText("Test", center, center, paint);
}
```

[image]

As you can see in the above image, the text "Test" is being drawn, but I am also seeing 2 horizontal lines above the text.

There is no other drawing done in green, and if I comment out `c.drawText(...`, I lose the text, and the lines.

Does anyone have any insight as to what might be causing this artifact? I have tried searching, and found no other posts with a similar issue.

Comment: Where do you initialize your paint?

Comment: @Cloud57 I have edited the above code to show the initialization.

Comment: Well this is so strange, but can you initialize a default Paint() and remove every attribute you set? Then if there is no problems, you try to set them one by one(in the constructor, not in onDraw) every test you do until you get the artifact.